# How to test my bench-marking functions?

Tags: benchmarking

I have written benchmarking functions from my pallet. How I can test these benchmarking functions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the following line to your benchmarking. For example like in [`pallet-assets`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6cb4b6799de6f784f4c42eb01a76a8fa67039a67/frame/assets/src/benchmarking.rs#L472). Make sure to adjust it to your needs.

```rust
impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
    MyPallet,
    crate::mock::new_test_ext(),
    crate::mock::Test
)
```

This will create a unit test for each benchmark and run it a few times with different values for each component. Starting the tests looks like this:

```rust
cargo test -p pallet-whatever --features runtime-benchmarks
```

as described in the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/test/benchmark/) and [README.md](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/6cb4b6799de6f784f4c42eb01a76a8fa67039a67/frame/benchmarking#testing-benchmarks).
If you try this for example for the lottery pallet, you should see the following output:

```
test benchmarking::bench_start_lottery ... ok
test benchmarking::bench_stop_repeat ... ok
test benchmarking::bench_on_initialize_end ... ok
test benchmarking::bench_set_calls ... ok
test benchmarking::bench_buy_ticket ... ok
test benchmarking::bench_on_initialize_repeat ... ok
```

Each line is the output of one benchmark unit-test.
Please not that benchmark tests are no-std and that normally you cannot use functions from the `mock.rs` since it is std. You can, however, create a `nostd_mock.rs` with helper functions that are usable from tests and benchmarks.

Comment: Dear @Oliver, Thank you very much for your time. Let me try it to mark this as answer. Just one followup question. We will run it from the node (in which we have added that pallet)  or from within the pallet itself?

Comment: The tests run in the mocked runtime completely without any node runtime.  
The benchmarks will then indeed need the node's runtime to produce the correct weights.

Comment: After running this command in my pallet the output is: "running 0 tests".  So there are no test running

Comment: How am I supposed to check without source code?