# Testing benchmarks with V2

Tags: benchmarking, testing, benchmark

Im writing benchmarks for a pallet using benchmarking version 2. And it seems I cant call `Pallet::<Test>::test_benchmarks_"extrinsic_name"` inside of a test anymore.

Is it no longer needed?

Comment: It was never necessary to call any of these internal functions manually. Daan mentions the advised way below.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the [`impl_benchmark_test_suite`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/bc5005217a8c2e7c95b9011c96d7e619879b1200/substrate/frame/benchmarking/src/v1.rs#L1444) macro which generates those tests for your benchmarks ([detailed explanation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/how-to-test-my-bench-marking-functions)).